# netty client hangs on connect

Tags: netty, deadlock

I am using a SMPP library called Cloudhopper which uses under the hood netty 3.9.9 to connect to a SMPP server. When the connection drops, I try to reconnect. In most cases this works, but sometimes the reconnection hangs. The piece of code in question is (or see https://github.com/twitter/cloudhopper-smpp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudhopper/smpp/impl/DefaultSmppClient.java#L286):

```
// a socket address used to "bind" to the remote system
InetSocketAddress socketAddr = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);

// set the timeout
this.clientBootstrap.setOption("connectTimeoutMillis", connectTimeoutMillis);

// attempt to connect to the remote system
ChannelFuture connectFuture = this.clientBootstrap.connect(socketAddr);

connectFuture.awaitUninterruptibly();
```

The clientBootstrap gets reused everytime. A threaddump looks like this:

```
"Sender Heartbeat 1" prio=10 tid=0x00007f0b50feb800 nid=0x7fa in Object.wait() [0x00007f0b849e2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000caa999b0> (a org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.awaitUninterruptibly(DefaultChannelFuture.java:259)
    - locked <0x00000000caa999b0> (a org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture)
    at com.cloudhopper.smpp.impl.DefaultSmppClient.createConnectedChannel(DefaultSmppClient.java:286)
    at com.cloudhopper.smpp.impl.DefaultSmppClient.doOpen(DefaultSmppClient.java:224)
    at com.cloudhopper.smpp.impl.DefaultSmppClient.bind(DefaultSmppClient.java:193)
```

Someone is not sending the notify to DefaultChannelFuture. Does anyone has any idea how to investigate it further? What is causing netty not to send the notify? So far I wasn't able to reproduce it locally, so I couldn't debug it.

I filed a bug report at the cloudhopper library but I was hoping that I could find out more and maybe even contribute a fix.

Cheers
Ruwen

Cheers
Ruwen

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to fix it with the following workaround (just in case anyone has the same problem):

```
    if (!connectFuture.await(connectTimeoutMillis + 1000)) {
        logger.error("connectFuture did not finish in expected time! Try to cancel the connectFuture");
        boolean isCanceled = connectFuture.cancel();
        logger.error("connectFuture: isCanceled {} isDone {} isSuccess {}", isCanceled, connectFuture.isDone(), connectFuture.isSuccess());
        throw new SmppChannelConnectTimeoutException("Could not connect to the server within timeout");
    }
```

Given that the Netty version (3.9.6.Final) is pretty old, I did not file a bug in the Netty project. But I added a PR to the cloudhopper project.